# Difference between np.dtype and np.dtype.name

Tags: python, numpy

As stated in the title, I am willing to know the difference between `np.dtype` and `np.dtype.name`. When I used them, I found that they provide same output like below:

```py
dt = np.array([[(1, 5, 2), (2, 4.0, 7)], [(6, 4, 2), (2, 8, 10)]])
print('\nData type of array elements:', dt.dtype)
print('\nName of data type:', dt.dtype.name)
```

Output is

> Data type of array elements: float64
>
> Name of data type: float64

Comment: The first returns the dtype class object and the second the name of that class as a string. You can check those with type(dt.dtype) and type(dt.dtype.name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [62]: arr = np.array([[(1, 5, 2), (2, 4.0, 7)], [(6, 4, 2), (2, 8, 10)]])
In [63]: arr
Out[63]: 
array([[[ 1.,  5.,  2.],
        [ 2.,  4.,  7.]],

       [[ 6.,  4.,  2.],
        [ 2.,  8., 10.]]])
```

For this simple `dtype`, the `name` is the same as the `str/print` representation.

```
In [64]: arr.dtype
Out[64]: dtype('float64')      # the repr print
In [65]: arr.dtype.name
Out[65]: 'float64'
In [66]: print(arr.dtype)
float64
```

But it's possible to construct more complex dtypes where the name and the display are different.  For example, since your constructor has inner tuples, I can create an array with a compound dtype, a `structured` array:

```
In [69]: arr = np.array([[(1, 5, 2), (2, 4.0, 7)], [(6, 4, 2), (2, 8, 10)]], dtype='i,f,f8')
In [70]: arr
Out[70]: 
array([[(1, 5.,  2.), (2, 4.,  7.)],
       [(6, 4.,  2.), (2, 8., 10.)]],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<f4'), ('f2', '<f8')])
In [71]: arr.dtype
Out[71]: dtype([('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<f4'), ('f2', '<f8')])
In [72]: arr.dtype.name
Out[72]: 'void128'
In [73]: arr.dtype.fields
Out[73]: 
mappingproxy({'f0': (dtype('int32'), 0),
              'f1': (dtype('float32'), 4),
              'f2': (dtype('float64'), 8)})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you print an object it asks the object what to print i.e. it calls it's "**repr**" method. Python objects always have that but you can define them yourself. E.g.

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

print(foo())
```

gives me `<__main__.foo object at 0x10b737280>`

while

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __repr__(self):
        return "__repr__"

print(foo())
```

gives me `__repr__`.

So an object of numpy type float64 has two methods that give you the name. One for you to call by hand and one for python to call implicitly if you asking for a string representation of the object e.g. if you print it.

You can see that more clearly like this

```
dt = np.array([[(1, 5, 2), (2, 4.0, 7)], [(6, 4, 2), (2, 8, 10)]])
print('Type of data type of array elements:', type(dt.dtype))
print('Type of name of data type:', type(dt.dtype.name)).
```

It gives you

```
Type of data type of array elements: <class 'numpy.dtype[float64]'>
Type of name of data type: <class 'str'>
```